# bitcoin repo sighash.json data format

Tags: transactions, development, bitcoin-core-development

Bitcoin enthusiast here. Learning "the hard way" how bitcoin works (andreas books, looking in js/python implementations), I'm writing (as an hobby) some code here and there to understand things and to test it, I'm using the tests available on the bitcoin github repo. But now, I'm struggling with the ones on the `sighash.json` file.

**What is the encoding format used for the raw transactions ?** (first element on each array).

I understand the traditional format which looks like 0100000000010280e688...000ffffffffe9b54...39da98ac00000000. But here I'm honestly lost. On the tests file, it doesn't look like a regular transaction.

[Example](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/test/data/sighash.json#L3):

```
907c2bc503ade11cc3b04eb2918b6f547b0630ab569273824748c87ea14b0696526c66ba74020000004ab65ababfd1f9bdd4ef073c7afc4ae00da8a66f429c917a0081ad1e1dabce28d373eab81d8628de802000000096aab5253ab52000052ad042b5f25efb33beec9f3364e8a9139e8439d9d7e26529c3c30b6c3fd89f8684cfd68ea0200000009ab53526500636a52ab599ac2fe02a526ed040000000008535300516352515164370e010000000003006300ab2ec229
```

**How am I supposed to decode such string ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You decode them in exactly the same way that you decode a transaction. They are perfectly valid transactions and a decoder should be able to decode them properly and get meaningful data out of them. The reason they look weird is because every part of the transaction is [randomly generated](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/test/sighash_tests.cpp#L95) so the fields do not necessarily contain data that you expect (e.g. the version number is randomly generated instead of the standard `01000000` or `02000000`).